# Can you solve my odd Sharepoint CSS cache / customising problem?

Tags: css, sharepoint, caching, solution

I have a weird situation with my sharepoint css.

It is deployed as part of a .wsp solution and up until now everything has been fine.

The farm it deploys too has a couple of webfront ends and a single apps server and SQL box.

The symptom is that if I deploy the solution, then use a webbrowser to view the page it has no styles, and if I access the .css directly I see the first 100 or so bytes of the .css.

However if I go into sharepoint designer and look at the file it is looks fine, and if I check it out and publish it (customising the file but not actually changing anything in it) then the website works fine and the css downloads completely.

There is some fairly complex caching on the servers Disk based and object caches. as far as I can tell I have cleared these (and an issreset should clear them anyway... shouldn't it?)

I have used this tool to clear the blobcache from the whole farm http://blobcachefarmflush.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you're describing is one I've encountered before.  Let me share what I know, what I suspect, and how I'd go about troubleshooting your scenario.

First off, it sounds like you suspect caching as a potential problem source.  In the case of the MOSS publishing feature set, you really have three different cache mechanisms in operation: the object cache, the BLOB cache, and the page output cache.  The only mechanism that should be in-play, assuming it's turned on with default settings, is the BLOB cache.  Neither the object cache nor the page output cache should be touching stand-alone stylesheets like you have.

You've tried flushing the cache the flush using the farm-level BLOB cache flush feature, and that will instruct MOSS to dump all BLOB cache data.  You can verify this by reviewing the file system to ensure that only the three .bin folders remain following a flush.

To your specific question regarding an IISRESET: no, and IISRESET actually *won't* clear the BLOB cache.  The contents of the BLOB cache persist beyond the life of the application pool servicing the web application.  You either need to use a feature to clear out the cache (as you have been), or perform a manual file delete.  I don't recommend the latter unless you absolutely have no other course of action.  If you do elect to go the manual route to try it, ensure that you shutdown the W3SVC service before deleting files out of the file system.  If you don't, the actual file deletion process can get into a race condition with cache repopulation and lead to corruption.  After you've deleted files with a stopped W3SVC, you can start the W3SVC back up again.

For more information on the internals of the BLOB cache and how it operates, I'll point you to a blog article of mine: http://sharepointinterface.com/2009/06/18/we-drift-deeper-into-the-sound-as-the-flush-comes/

To see if the BLOB cache is a factor in the behavior you're seeing, you can modify the web.config for your web application(s) and adjust the file pattern to remove **CSS** from the list of file types in the **<BlobCache>** element and then restart IIS (or at least recycle the app pool).

Another possibility, based on experience, is that you're seeing something other than BLOB cache abnormalities.  The key observation for me comes in the form of you observing that a direct request for the CSS stylesheet returns only the first 100 bytes or so.

Do you, by any chance, have any intelligent network hardware (that is, intrusion detection hardware or anything that might be performing application/layer-7 filtering) between the WFE and you, the caller?  Intrusion detection and IPS systems are the source of many of the types of problems you're seeing, and they're one of my first stops whenever I see "oddball" behavior like you're describing.  In the case of one of my clients, I saw a problem meeting your description (CSS and JS files getting truncated) due to an intervening Juniper firewall with active IPS.  Turning off IPS (to test) cleared things up immediately.  After that, the networking team sought an update from Juniper to correct the issue to ensure that IPS could remain active.

Try turning off BLOB caching (or removing the CSS extension from the file pattern) to see if that makes a difference.  If not, talk to your network team to see if something is happening to the response stream coming back to you.  That's where I'd start; hopefully, one of those two things will do the trick for you.

Small side note: if you have a free moment and are up to it, I'd like to hear about your experience with the BlobCacheFarmFlush solution you pulled down from CodePlex.  I authored it, and I'd love to hear your thoughts -- good or bad  :-)

- Sean (sean@sharepointinterface.com)

Comment: Thanks for your super comprehensive answer. I shall investigate the IPS etc that sits between us and the (remotely hosted) Sharepoint farm. We certainly have had plenty of firewall problems getting different bits of our and their systems to talk to each other.

Comment: Hope the information proves useful to you, Aidan.  If neither of the suggestions do anything for you (and I'd be surprised if that were the case), post again.  Good luck!